# How to refresh explorer after mounting to show mounted drive in VC++?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, shell, shell32

I am using driver code for mounting FTP Drives with NPAddConnection3 now the problem is when i mount the drive it gets mounted but i need to kill explorer and restart manually to see the mounted drive .

How to solve this problem ?
How i can get see mounted drive without killing the explorer ?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call SHChangeNotify - depending on how you register your driver pick SHCNE_ADDDRIVE, SHCNE_NETSHARE etc.

Docs here on MSDN:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762118(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Stephbhu : Can u pls give me a example  ?

Comment: There are plenty of samples of calling it on the web and MSDN